# Hindu Mythologies related to "Chandra" God

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, chandra

[Chandra](https://www.astroved.com/astropedia/en/planets/chandra)

Are there Hindu Mythologies related to "Chandra" God?

Comment: He kidnapped Brihaspati’s wife and started the Chandravamsha of Kshatriyas, got cursed by Daksha saved by Lord Shiva.

Comment: Good question.Ganesha was returning home on his mount Krauncha (a shrew) late on a full moon night after a mighty feast given by Kubera. A snake crossed their path and frightened , vahan ran away , Ganesh fell. Ganesha fell  on his stomach, vomiting out all the Modaks .Chandra laughed at Ganesha. Angry Ganesha broke off one tusks and flung it at the Moon, hurting him, and cursed him -he would never be whole again. So it is forbidden to behold Chandra on Ganesh Chaturthi. This legend accounts for the Moon's waxing and waning .